# How to phase out SHA-1 based Signature

Tags: html, algorithm, security, certificate, ssl-certificate

I have been getting the following warning on my website :

> This site makes use of a SHA-1 Certificate; it's recommended you use
>   certificates with signature algorithms that use hash functions
>   stronger than SHA-1.

Which leads to [Phasing Out Certificates with SHA-1 based Signature Algorithms](https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2014/09/23/phasing-out-certificates-with-sha-1-based-signature-algorithms/)

It recommends we can use `SHA-256, SHA-384, or SHA-512`

But the **Question** is how do I actually change it ?

Thanks.

Comment: This entirely depends on how you obtained your certificate in the first place. Typically you would have to request a new certificate from your original provider. Whether they will charge you or not is up to them.

Comment: when you say original provider do you mean service provider ?.

Comment: I mean whoever generated and/or signed your current SSL certificate.